# Pull specific lines of a CSV based on the line contents

Tags: python, csv

I download weekly CSV files for which I only need a few specific lines of data. All of the relevant lines begin with "Invoice" which is the criteria I want Python to look for. I'm just not sure how to tell the program to do that.

I've tried using this:

```
import csv
with open("OpenInvList_9428.csv" , 'rb') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        if "Invoice" in row:
            print ','.join(row)
```

I know something with this statement is wrong:

```
if "Invoice" in row:
```

I'm just not sure what.

Comment: Your code had a mix of tabs and spaces, and was indented 3 spaces instead of 4, so it came out as an unreadable mess. Please verify that the fixed version looks like your code and does the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried printing out what `row` is?

Comment: fixed code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line begins with `Invoice`, then the first column in the line must begin with `Invoice`, right? So:

```
with open("OpenInvList_9428.csv" , 'rb') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        if row[0].startswith('Invoice'):
            print ','.join(row)
```

You attempt, `if "Invoice" in row:`, checks to see if any of the columns are exactly `"Invoice"`—that is, if the row starts with `Invoice,` it'll work, but if it starts with `Invoice 23,`, it won't. That's because `row` is a list of strings, not a string, and that's what `in` does with lists.

If you want to check whether *any* of the columns have `Invoice` as a substring, that's:

```
if any('Invoice' in column for column in row):
```

Or, to check whether any of the columns start with `Invoice`:

```
if any(column.startswith('Invoice') for column in row):
```

---

However, if the only reason you want to parse the CSV is to join it back up into another CSV, why are you doing it in the first place? If there's no quoting in the CSV, you can do the same thing more simply like this:

```
with open("OpenInvList_9428.csv" , 'rb') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('Invoice'):
            print line
```

And there, `'Invoice' in line` would find it if `Invoice` is a substring of any column (because in that case it's a substring of the line).

And if there *is* any quoting, you're generating invalid output, while the simpler code is getting it right.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. The second batch of code worked perfectly, printing just the invoice rows.